# Check if max-width is set, in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to check if an inline style has already been applied by jQuery.

Normally, I would do something like this:

`if ($(this).css('max-width') == '20%') {}`

However, **I don't know the percentage.** What is the best way to check if there is **any** max-width applied?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default `.css('max-width')` will return `"none"` if no `max-width` was defined, so the following condition should do the job:

```
if ($(this).css('max-width') !== 'none') { ... }
```

If you need to check for *inline style only*, meaning that you override the original `max-width` CSS property (e.g. from the stylesheet file), you may do the following:

```
if (this.style.maxWidth !== '') { ... }
```

... as pure `maxWidth` property of `style` will be empty `""` if the CSS property was not set.

Comment: OP says 'inline style', would this not check not inline style?

Comment: @Reigel Fair enough. Updated the answer with corresponding description.

Comment: Perfect! What's the difference between `$(this)` and `this`, is the first a jQuery exclusive object?

Comment: @tmyie `$(this)` will create a jQuery object out of `this` DOM element.

Answer (score 2):

```
if ( $(this).css('max-width')!='none' ) { }
```

Answer (score 2):

If on a element the `max-width` property is not applied then it will return `none`.
Try to check `none`

```
$(this).css('max-width') =='none'
```

OR

```
if( $('#element').css('max-width') =='none' )  { 
 // max-width not EXISTS
} 
else
{
 // max-width EXISTS
}
```

**Checking only the `inline style` :**

```
if($('#element').attr('style') != 'undefined'){
 if( $('#element').attr('style').indexOf('max-width') == -1 )  { 
  // max-width not EXISTS
 } 
 else
 {
   // max-width EXISTS
 }
}
else
{
  // Inline style not EXISTS
}
```

OR

**I recommend to use Jquery selector [Attribute Contains Word Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)**

```
$('div[style ~= "min-width:"]')
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g7Pqr/4/)

Comment: another way to get inline-style is using the pure JS `style` property (`style.maxWidth`). Normaly it should return the inline-style, otherwise it returns empty, hence we have to use `getComputedStyle` or the jQuery method `css` to get style set in CSS file.

Comment: @KingKing: Yes this is pure JS, And if we want to use Jquery, we could use Jquery selectors. (Please see updated answer) :)